# When is a $*$-homomorphism between multiplier algebras strictly continuous?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, reference-request, gn.general-topology

(This question was posted on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300276/when-is-a-homomorphism-between-multiplier-algebras-strictly-continuous) but didn't get any answers.)

The strict topology on the multiplier algebra M(A) of a C*-algebra A is that generated by the seminorms

$$ x\mapsto \|ax\|\quad x\mapsto \|xa\| \qquad (a\in A, x\in M(A)) $$

Whereas a ∗-homomorphism $\phi : M(A)\to M(B)$ between two multiplier algebras is necessarily norm-continuous, if I understand things correctly it will not always be continuous with respect to the strict topologies on either side.  **Where is there a good reference for this?**

On the other hand an easily-proven theorem states that $\phi$ is strictly continuous if the image of $\phi$ contains B. This is not necessary, however; take $\phi : \mathcal{B}(\ell^2)\to\mathcal{B}(\ell^2)$ to be the map $x\mapsto sxs^*$ where $s$ is the unilateral shift. This is strictly continuous even though its image doesn't contain $\mathcal{K}(\ell^2)$. **Are there other conditions which guarantee $\phi$ to be strictly continuous?**

I'm particularly interested in the case where $\phi$ maps A into B, and both are nonunital.  **Is this enough to show that $\phi$ is strictly continuous?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-degenerate *-homorphism from $A$ (or $M(A)$) to $M(B)$ are strict (where non-degenerate means that $\phi(A)B$ is total in $B$). An important property of strict maps $\phi:A\to M(B)$  is that they possess a unique strict extension $\tilde{\phi}:M(A)\to M(B)$.

A good reference is

E.C. Lance, Hilbert C∗-modules, London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series
210, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1995.

Comment: Thanks, Uwe; upon looking at Lance's book, it seems that nondegeneracy is also a necessary condition for $\phi$ to be strict (assuming $\phi$ is unital).  I'm still unsure of the answer for the third question, though.

Comment: Unital in which sense? For $\phi(1)=1$, $A$ has to be unital and then you have $M(A)=A$.

Comment: I think Paul means $\tilde\phi$ unital.